# Can an ADC be damaged by applying a higher voltage than VREF but that is still within specs?

Tags: adc, maximum-ratings

Take the following example:
A SAR ADC that is rated for 5v and 3v3 operation is operated at 3v3 (for both VDD and VREF). Someone is a bit careless and applies 5v to one of the inputs. Can this permanently damage the ADC in any way?

A slightly detailed explanation for why or why not would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be written in the datasheet.

If the absolute max rating that applies for the input pins is given as "5.5V", you're fine. If it is given as something like "VDD + 0.5V", you're not fine.

Every bit of information *and the way it is written* makes sense in a datasheet. Always.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1. Unless there is a mistake in it. Which happens, too... And when it does, that sucks.</sup>

Comment: My issue though is that these values are usually given in the general electrical specification not in the absolute maximum ratings. It makes sense that the ADC wouldn't work to spec (or at all) when I just apply a higher voltage than VREF but it doesn't really answer the question whether or not it would be damaging.

Comment: And how can an ADC (or IC in general) be limited to f.e. VDD+0.5v at VDD=3.3v but still allow VDD=5v? Where is this variable limitation coming from?

Comment: @ProfessorSparkles There may be (often will be) a protection diode from pin to Vdd. Diode conducts when forward biased.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense

Comment: It answers the question since I'm referring to the *absolute* ratings, which is a specific chapter in every datasheet that give the limits beyond whuch the chip may be damaged. So we're talking about the same thing.

Comment: Oh sure I just wanted some more detail, your answer is absolutely fine!

Answer (score 3):

Logic ICs, even mixed-signal parts like an ADC, typically have undershoot and overshoot protection diodes that clamp input pins voltages to the positive and ground/negative supply rails.

Inclusion of these diodes is usually stated in the data sheet, sometimes obliquely by stating 'Absolute Maximum' input pin voltages as 'Vdd+0.6V' and 'GND-0.6V' or such like.

The current capability of these diodes is often not stated but, as a guide, clamping diodes in 74HC/74HCT families could handle 20 mA continuous. It is advisable to include a series input resistor before your ADC input pin that will limit the overshoot/undershoot input current to 1 mA or less.

Answer (score 0):

Very related to this are overshoots and undershoots during operation of the ADC; the injected charge, as the ESD diodes turn on, has to find a RETURN path. If that moving charge upsets the charge on the sample-hold capacitors, or upsets the comparator decisions, your 10 bit ADC will be flakey.

In a 16 or 20 or 24 bit ADC, the mere presence of a few hundred milliVoltPP on SPI pins, even with logic levels being "0" or "1", will inject charge and upset the performance. There is a famous IC design house in Plano, I believe, that placed 16-bit ADC on chip with a hard-working MCU; the ADC was only good for 8-bits unless the MCU was put to sleep; this is what I was told.

You CAN integrate noisy digital with quiet analog, on the same silicon die, but you must provide "quiet time", often 100 nanoseconds long, or accept poor analog decision-making. There is a famous chip company in Dallas that acquired a famous DAC/ADC company; the Dallas company integrated some of the newly owned IP --- a 24bit ADC --- with a 32MHz MCU; I did not believe the 24-bit ADC performance would remain...24 bits; careful reading of the datasheet reveals the truth: the MCU must be throttled down, to 8MHz or 125nanoSecond period, to achieve the ADC's 24 bits.

If you examine the datasheets for the LLTC 24 bit (standalone) ADCs, you may notice the SPI pins (3 of them) are given special isolation, not directly connected to any computer bus.

Are these caveats -------permanently damaging? Do we call it "damage" when the 16-bit ADC only provides 8-bit performance?

Comment: While interesting to read, I'm not quite sure how it answers my question? Do you mean to say the operation of the ADC will suffer from over-voltage but the IC itself not damaged? In my case I'm talking about a continuous over-voltage not just ns long spikes.